# Renaming files with Python doesn't seem to work (os.rename)

Tags: python, automation

```
import time, os

timestamp = time.strftime('%d.%m_%H:%M')

while True:
    print("Beginning checkup")
    print("=================")
    for fname in os.listdir("C:/SOURCE"):
        if fname.endswith(".txt"):
            print("found " + fname)
            os.rename(fname, fname.replace(fname, timestamp + ".txt"))
            time.sleep(5)
```

This is the code I have. What its supposed to do is look for .txt files in SOURCE and add a timestamp to the name. This somehow gives me a "FileNotFoundError". Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Windows can not have colons `:` in filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems

- `os.listdir` returns the filename, without the path.
- timestamp has a `:`, you cannot use that as a file name
- you rename your files into the same one because your substitution isn't working properly!

So when renaming you have to use `os.path.join` to provide full path to `os.rename()`

The next issue is that your replacement to add a timestamp is *wrong*. It doesn't add the timestamp but replaces the filename completely.

```
fname.replace(fname, timestamp + ".txt"))
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
timestamp + ".txt"
```

Another minor issue is that if a file ends with `.TXT` it is not detected by your filter. It's better to use `fnmatch` module for complex wildcards. In your case, I just applied `lower()`.

my complete fix proposal, which inserts a timestamp on all txt files of your directory:

```
timestamp = time.strftime('%d_%m_%H_%M') # only underscores: no naming issues
the_dir = "C:/SOURCE"
for fname in os.listdir(the_dir):
    if fname.lower().endswith(".txt"):
        print("found " + fname)
        new_name = "{}_{}.txt".format(os.path.splitext(fname)[0],timestamp)
        os.rename(os.path.join(the_dir,fname), os.path.join(the_dir,new_name))
```

Of course you could also `os.chdir` to the proper directory, but that isn't advised in a complex application because that could break other parts of the application.

You may prefer an alternative to compute absolute path & filter only on txt files using `glob`

```
import glob

for fname in glob.glob(os.path.join("C:/SOURCE","*.txt")):
   # now fname bears the absolute path
```

Comment: Damn that seems logical, I'm gonna take a look.

Comment: Seems to work, but the path-formatting seems to be for linux because it adds // to the path which doesnt work on windows. How do I fix that?

Comment: path formatting works fine on windows. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Ah okay was an error on my end, works now. Thanks for the complete spoonfeed, I'll try to understand your code